# How to solve the wrong output in rod cutting problem

Tags: c++, c++11, dynamic-programming

```
int max_val(int l) {
  // input l
  int val[] = {1, 5, 8, 9, 10, 17, 17, 20, 24, 30};
  if (l == 0)
    return 0;
  auto q = INT16_MIN;
  for (auto i = 0; i < l; i++) {
    q = std::max(q, val[i] + max_val(l - i - 1));
    std::cout << "  " << q;
    // ----->1
  }
  std::cout << " " << q;
  // ----->2
}
```

I tried this and at points 1 and 2 (marked with `----->`) output is a very long number and I do not get the correct output when done in this way for all previous recursive problems. If I remove output `q` and return `q` at the end the code runs right.

The aim is to maximize value for given length of rod.
Can anyone please explain what's wrong in this. The `val` is value array for each rod pieces i.e., 1 piece value 1, 2 pieces of value 5 etc till 10 and letter `l` is length of rod input. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your function doesn't return for all paths, but have non void return type.

Comment: you cannot simply make it return `void`, because you are using the return value here `val[i] + max_val(l - i - 1)`

Comment: You have UB as you don't return `q` at the end.

Comment: And are you sure `l <= length of val`?

Comment: What is meaning of UB?

Comment: Undefined behavior. So anything can happens.

Comment: Undefined behavior means your entire program is meaningless. The compiler can assume that UB never happens, so if you cause UB all sorts of weird crap can happen. Since you have a function that is supposed to return a value but you never actually return anything, it might end up returning some random value, or it might return the correct value and appear to work, or it could cause your program to output "WHAT THE CRAP!!"